# Repository and Aggregate Roots in Domain Driven Design

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am building a notification system, where I have users that can create subscriptions which define when a notification will be delivered to them and by which endpoint. I have established that a User is an Aggregate Root, and will have a Repository for them. I am having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around this concept though. From my understanding, only Aggregate Roots should be pulled from a Repository.

Let's say I have a User

```
public class User
{
    public ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Endpoint> Endpoints {get; set;}
}
```

This User has a collection of Subscriptions and Endpoints. Both of these are Entities themselves, as their contents can change without it being a different object. For instance, both these entities can be enabled/disabled. They cannot exist outside the context of a User, as only a User can create a Subscription or an Endpoint.

My Subscription also contains a reference to an Endpoint, as this Subscription needs to know where to deliver.

```
public class Subscription
{
    public ICollection<Endpoint> Endpoints {get; set;}
}
```

So, as I have defined the User as the Aggregate Root, I now have a UserRepository for persisting my users. Any modifications to an Endpoint or a Subscription would be done within the context of a User being the Aggregate Root. This makes sense to me. But what if I want to retrieve a list of Subscriptions which meet a set of Criteria. The system which handles triggering a notification will receive an event, and need to query for a set of Subscriptions that are relevant to that event. The event is not user based, as multiple Users can have Subscriptions which are valid for this event. Would I put a method on my UserRepository which returns these Subscriptions? Or would I create a SubscriptionRepository? If I create the SubscriptionRepository, would that not mean that a Subscription is an Aggregate Root as well? If the answer to that question is yes, then does my design violate the concept of an AggregateRoot since both User and Subscription contain a reference to an Endpoint entity?

Answer (score 2):

First of, it puzzles me why do you have Endpoints in a User and Subscriptions? Can you maybe delete the Endpoints in User or that doesn't make sense?

Second, ask yourself

> If I delete a User, do I always have to delete all of his subscriptions and endpoints?

If the answer is no, then a User is not an aggregate root. By your description I believe that you defined your Aggregate Roots wrong.
If you'd really have an AR, you'd never have a need for a separate repository that questions for its entities. They're only called with the AR and manipulated (filtered, changed etc.) within its context.

Subscription could be a part of the process that involves a User and adding Subscriptions to it. Maybe Subscription is AR with its Enpoints.

Comment: Endpoints in my domain are things like PhoneNumbers, EmailAddresses, etc. I have Endpoints in User because a User has PhoneNumbers and EmailAddresses. I have Endpoints in a Subscription, because a User will Subscribe to have a notification sent to his PhoneNumber or EmailAddress. And yes, when I delete a User, ALL of that users Endpoints and Subscriptions are deleted as well. They cannot exist without the user which created them.

I have a desire to retrieve a User with all its Endpoints and Subscriptions, and I have a desire to retrieve a set of Subscriptions which match an event.

Answer (score 2):

> From my understanding, only Aggregate Roots should be pulled from a Repository.

That's not quite right.  The *repository* is an abstraction in front of your persistence solution.  Any state that you pull from the book of record should come through a repository.

Aggregates are specific to use cases where you are modifying the book of record -- in other words, when you are doing writes.

If you aren't going to change anything, then you don't need to (re)check that the data within the aggregate boundaries is consistent.  Views, reports, analytics -- these use cases don't need aggregates, because they don't produce any new state that needs to be preserved in the book of record.

(CQRS: reads have different requirements than writes).

The key idea is that only aggregate roots should be *saved* in the repository.

So if you have a use case that needs to read snapshots of the state of `Endpoints` across multiple aggregates, then design a [repository interface](http://udidahan.com/2007/03/28/query-objects-vs-methods-on-a-repository/) that documents that requirement, and make sure that repository *doesn't include save*.

Comment: Okay, then as long as my repository only allows for Aggregate Roots to be saved, I should be okay to retrieve whatever child entities in a read-only fashion. The only way to change that child would be to modify it through an Aggregate Root, which in my case is a User. And since the repository only allows a User to be saved, I am safe.